# Numerical treatment of radiation boundary condition for 1D implicit heat conduction

Tags: boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, implicit-differentiation

I have a question regarding the $\textbf{radiation boundary treatment}$ for the 1D heat conduction equation using the $\textbf{implicit}$ finite difference method.

If I use the $\textbf{explicit}$ method, I can do it easily as the equation below. Namely, all the values at the previous time step $i$ is known, so $T^{i+1}$ can easily be calculated, including the internal nodes.

$$\varepsilon\sigma[T_{sur}^4-(T_0^i)^4]+k \frac{T_1^i-T_0^i}{\Delta x}=\rho\frac{\Delta x}{2}C_p\frac{T^{i+1}-T_0^i}{\Delta x}$$

However, if I want to solve it $\textbf{implicitly}$, the equation becomes:

$$\varepsilon\sigma[T_{sur}^4-(T_0^{i+1})^4]+k \frac{T_1^{i+1}-T_0^{i+1}}{\Delta x}=\rho\frac{\Delta x}{2}C_p\frac{T_0^{i+1}-T_0^i}{\Delta x}$$

If I don't have the radiation term $\varepsilon\sigma[T_{sur}^4-(T_0^{i+1})^4]$, then I can easily rewrite the equations, including those for internal nodes, to $[A]\cdot[T^{i+1}]=[B]$. With this,       $T^{i+1}$ can be calculated with the matrix inversion.

Nevertheless, if we have the radiative term, then we have a term $(T^{i+1})^4$, which can not be added into the linear equation system $[A]\cdot[T^{i+1}]=[B]$. How could we treat this implicitly then? I do need some help here.

Answer (score 1):

This comes late, but the normal approach is to linearize the Stefan-Boltzmann term by factorization, so that the LHS  radiation term becomes:

$$-\varepsilon\sigma[(T_0)^4-(T_{sur})^4] = -\varepsilon\sigma[T_0+T_{sur}][T_0-T_{sur}][(T_0)^2+(T_{sur})^2]$$

At first inspection this doesn't look very helpful, but if you collect the terms in the correct form, you can see it is possible to treat this as a generic Robin (i.e. linear) boundary condition:

$$-\varepsilon\sigma[(T_0)^4-(T_{sur})^4] = -h[T_0-T_{sur}]$$

with
$$h = \varepsilon\sigma[T_0+T_{sur}][(T_0)^2+(T_{sur})^2]$$

To implement this in a direct implicit linear solver, use $T_0=T_0^{i+1}$ in the Robin boundary condition, and $T_0=T_0^{i}$ in the calculation of the Robin coefficient $h$. This normally gives a useful approximation as long as the temperature change between timesteps isn't too long. In an iterative scheme, you can use the same idea, but update the value of $h$ with $T_0^{i+1}$ at each iteration, or include the analytical derivative of the term if you compute a Jacobian for the solver.